# How to run an UI program without being logged in?

Tags: windows-server-2016

I have a very stupidly written executable that converts database into another format. The application is automatic, but it display progress window, so it can't be run with scheduler (tried it).

Any ideas how to make the app run?

I tried: tricking it with .bat, making special user to be always logged in for the task to run, make an autoit runme exe file, used another scheduler tasker, etc. however whatever I do, the app either doesn't run or crashes.

All this is on Windows Server 2016. Thanks!

Comment: without knowing which application is, my only suggestion is to verify if the executable get a silent mode, by default with the flag "executable.exe /s" enable the silent mode; but this is for the installation, could you share the application name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run it with [NSSM](https://nssm.cc/). You can then start/stop the services with a scheduled task. NSSM allows you to let it "interact" with the desktop and give it a nearly complete logged on desktop.

Comment: I tried NSSM, but the application couldn't even start. I also tried System Scheduler, and the result was the same. Could it be that it starts in different environment from the logged on user?

Comment: It starts in the environment, you start it with. If you use the logged on user, it's using this ones. The only nssm-incompatible application I know is a 3d rendering ting which heavily uses gfx stuff (and therefor cannot run with an emulated desktop).